# dashcode error with java array se.mebe.Lion@7852e922, se.mebe.Zebra@4e25154f, se.mebe.Monkey@70dea4e

Tags: java

public void addAnimalsToZoo() {

```
    Animal[] zoo = new Animal[animals.length + 5];
    System.arraycopy(animals, 0, zoo, 0, animals.length);

    for (count = 0; count < zoo.length; count++)
        System.out.println("new animals with new array" + "\t" + zoo[count]);

}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: when i print out array i get hashcode how can i get string

Comment: @JOJO read the answer. it tells you what to do, and it explains why you now get such results.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't override the `toString` method in your Animal class.

```
System.out.println("new animals with new array" + "\t" + zoo[count]);
```

will print a concatenation of "new animals with new array", "\t" and the result of `toString` called on zoo[count].

If you don't override `toString`, the default one (from the Object class) will be used, which results in prints like: se.mebe.Zebra@4e25154f

Comment: did you mean like this System.out.println("new animals with new array" + "\t" + toString(zoo[count]));

Comment: you need to override toString() in your Animal class

Comment: no. I mean something like:
public String toString(){ return "result"; }

Comment: i tried but problem with return array , how to return the result in this case

Comment: you're not printing the array, you are printing an element from the array.